# How to get contacts from phone using react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Get contacts from phone using react native expo
I'm not getting it

Answer (score 7):

Use Contacts and Permissions, get user permission and then take the data as stated in the [Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/contacts.html). Here is an example: [Snack Contact Example](https://snack.expo.io/HyWyosROG)

```
async showFirstContactAsync() {
  // Ask for permission to query contacts.
  const permission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CONTACTS);

  if (permission.status !== 'granted') {
    // Permission was denied...
    return;
  }
  const contacts = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
    fields: [
      Contacts.PHONE_NUMBERS,
      Contacts.EMAILS,
    ],
    pageSize: 10,
    pageOffset: 0,
  });
  if (contacts.total > 0) {
    Alert.alert(
      'Your first contact is...',
      `Name: ${contacts.data[0].name}\n` +
      `Phone numbers: ${contacts.data[0].phoneNumbers[0].number}\n` +
      `Emails: ${contacts.data[0].emails[0].email}`
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get specific contacts, like I want all the contacts with names starting with the letter "a" or the contacts with specific phone numbers.

Comment: @BilalYaqoob you can just iterate the contacts.data Array and check if the current one starts with an 'a'. e.g. sth like contacts.data[i].name[0] == 'a'